# MongoDB insert vs update serialization difference for complex types

Tags: c#, mongodb

Does anyone know what is the difference in serialization for Update and Insert, and how to make it equal? The problem i'm having is as fallows:
Let's say we have the following class (ignore that it doesn't have MongoId as it's not relevant)

```
class Custom
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Dict { get; set; }
}
```

When I use Insert command resulting Json looks like this

```
{
    "ID" : "id",
    "Dict" :
    {
        "Key": "Val"
    }
}
```

This is as expected, but after using Update command Json changes to this

```
{
    "ID" : "id",
    "Dict" :
    {
        "_t" : "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]",
        "_v" :
        {
            "Key": "Val"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that BsonSerializer throws an error when it encounters _t/_v syntax. So, how can I make Update serialize the same as Insert?

Notes:
Driver version is 2.4.4
TDocument of IMongoCollection is always BsonDocument
Dictionary is only an example, this happens with any data type that has complex value including arrays

**Edit**
This is a simple version of a code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient client = new MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
    MongoDB.Driver.IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("TestBase");
    MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument> coll = db.GetCollection<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>("TestColl");
    Dictionary<string, string> tmpDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    object tmpDict_o = null;

    tmpDict.Add("Key", "Val");
    tmpDict_o = tmpDict;

    coll.DeleteMany(MongoDB.Driver.Builders<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty);

    coll.InsertOne(MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocumentWrapper.Create(new Custom() { ID = "id", Dict = tmpDict }));

    Console.ReadLine();

    coll.UpdateMany(MongoDB.Driver.Builders<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty, MongoDB.Driver.Builders<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>.Update.Set("Dict", tmpDict_o));
    }
```

If you change tmpDict_o to tmpDict in UpdateMany it will work as expected, but as I don't know what type of value the variable will have it must be stored in object. (Original function will take any type and extract property value with reflections)

**Edit 2**
Debugging through MongoDB.Driver I have found that mongo determent's which type the field is by looking at TDocument of IMongoCollection, and by using BsonDocument it will always take default serializer(for System.Object). So my next solution was to open two collections; one with BsonDocument for insert, and one with type used for update (in this example Custom). In this case update for dictionary went good, but arrays where even worse. String array was serialized as string with value "String[] Array", and array of complex type still has _t/_v syntax.

Comment: can we see complete code?

Comment: I don't have exact code with me at this moment, so I will edit my question tomorow. In short. Insert is done by creating document with BsonDocumentWrapper.Create and calling InsertOne. Update is done by building filter with Set("field", value) where value can be of any type (variable type is object) and calling UpdateMany.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. What I wrote in **Edit 2** is partially true, and document serializer will be set to BsonDocumentSerializer if TDocument is BsonDocument, but the field serializer will be resolved in Set method of UpdateDefinitionBuilder. Because variable is declared as

```
object tmpDict_o = null;
```

TField will always be object. To fix this behavior you can declare variable as

```
dynamic tmpDict_o = null;
```

so TField will be set to correct type.

Note:
While this solution works you must always declare your class as public, else it will fall back to _t/_v syntax for some reason.